# Why am I getting a conditional output when importing the Dirac Equation to Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, latex

Just starting out with Mathematica and trying to use the Dirac Equation. I'm working with the following form of the Dirac Equation:

$$
i \hbar \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi - m c \psi = 0
$$

And my input is the following:

```
ToExpression["i \hbar \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi - m c \psi = 0", TeX]
```

My expected output would be the Wolfram representation of the Dirac equation, but instead I'm getting a conditional. I'm guessing this is probably a novice mistake. The output Mathematica gives me is:

$$
\psi \neq 0 \ \&\& \ \mu == cm
$$

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for your help.

## Update Re: Duplicate

The suggested duplicate seems to answer most questions except for dealing with special symbols. It's understood that in the above, `\hbar` or $\hbar$ has to be imported. I am unaware of how to do this and appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: `ToExpression["i \hbar \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi - m c \psi = 0", \
TeXForm, Hold]` but this doesnt import `\hbar`

Comment: Reading from the two previous comments, I gather that 1) I am not properly escaping my "\" and 2) `\hbar` is not properly imported. Is `\hbar` not native to Wolfram and/or is there a link explaining how to "import" special symbols? Thanks!

Comment: Yes to both 1) and 2). And hbar is indeed not properly imported. As I say in the linked answer, the LaTeX import abilities are limited. It's usually best to write equations directly in *Mathematica* than to import them from LaTeX. It's sad but true. Maybe one can say something beyond this if you explain what you want to do with the imported formula.

Comment: @Jens got it, so in general sometimes I have to "guess" how to build the equation if something doesn't seem right through a little trial and error. Thanks for helping! I might try to post an answer to this for others having similar issues specifically with the Dirac Equation.

Comment: @Jens and sorry accidentally skipped over the second part of your comment. My goal is to start using Wolfram as a "worksheet" of the Dirac equation and start solving for different variables. So if wanted to something like a partial derivative, I could do so.

Comment: The ultimate problem is what I mentioned in my first comment: the goal of `ToExpression` is to create a *Mathematica* expression, and what you're getting is an expression that doesn't actually correspond to the Dirac equation mathematically, even if it visually looks like your LaTeX input. And that doesn't depend on $\hbar$ being there or not. It's the symbols $\mu$ in super and subscripts. Their meaning is lost.

Comment: Got it, so what you're saying is if I use Wolfram notation such as `\[Gamma]` Mathematica doesn't correspond to the Dirac equation mathematically? And I need to "fill in the blanks" and start creating matrices and functions.

Comment: I don't know what your goal is, but you can see what happens when you don't add the `Hold` attribute. The evaluation will give nonsense unless you're much more explicit in the LaTeX input.

Comment: Just in case someone stumbles on this from Google and is attempting to work with the Dirac equation, I found this notebook that had a lot of what I was looking for: http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/